Fourier transform of Heaviside radial function in 3D
I am trying to take the 3D Fourier transform of Heaviside Theta Function $$\Theta(r-r_c)$$, where for $r>r_c$, $\Theta(r-r_c)=1$ otherwise it is zero. I can do it the given way, but I want to avoid it. $$\int\Theta\left(r^{\prime}-r_{c}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}^{\prime}}d\mathbf{r}^{\prime}=1-\int\Theta\left(r_{c}-r^{\prime}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}^{\prime}}d\mathbf{r}^{\prime}$$ $$=\delta\left(\mathbf{\mathbf{k}}\right)-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Theta\left(r_{c}-r^{\prime}\right)e^{-i\left|\mathbf{\mathbf{k}}\right|r^{\prime}\cos\theta}r^{\prime2}\sin\theta dr^{\prime}d\theta d\phi$$ $$=\delta\left(\mathbf{\mathbf{k}}\right)-f\left(\left|\mathbf{\mathbf{k}}\right|\right)$$ Is it possible to do it in cartesian coordinates $?$. I am asking because I want to do it in cartesian coordinates, and I am unable to solve it in cartesian coordinates.

$\delta\left(\bf k\right)$ must be multiplied by $\left(2\pi\right)^{3}$. We choose the convenient one which, in this case, is the spherical one.

What is your definition of the theta function.

for $r>r_c$,  $\Theta(r-r_c)=1$ otherwise it is zero.
